# How can i do this css effect on classes using only jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```css
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-header > a:hover,
.navbar-header > a:focus {
  background-color: #7F613F;
}

.icon-color {
  color: #282828;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #b39369; max-height: 50px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="navbar-header">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 15px;">
                            <li><a class="icon-change" href="#" style="padding: 15px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment icon-color"></i></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

What i want is that if element has class `icon-change`, that class can get effect something like my  css effects.

In other words, What i want to know is how can i change that element's background color when mouse is on that element, or when mouse over that element.

For more example,

1. when mouse is in the class `icon-change`, i want `icon-change`'s background color be 'red'.
2. when mouse is over the class `icon-change`, i want `icon-change`'s color be 'blue'.
3. when i mouse click on the class `icon-change`, i want `icon-change`'s color be 'pink', and it's last until i re-click the class `icon-change`. In this re-clicked moment, re-clicked class `icon-change` is returned to fist status like there's nothing happened yet.

How can i do this through jQuery?

Comment: why do with jquery when you can do in css?

Comment: @guradio Although i mentioned for only background-color like css effect, I actually want to do other things with jQuery function like `console.log` or something.

Comment: so, you want to do something when the **mouse** is **over** an element? and undo it when the **mouse** is **out** ... or do you prefer to do something when the **mouse** **enter**s and undo when the **mouse** **leave**s ?

Comment: jquery has .css() method, but it is best used for dynamic css manipulation.

Comment: @JaromandaX oh, what i want is mouse enters and mouse leaves. Thanks

Comment: so, `.on('mouseenter'` and `.on('mouseleave'` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use .on() see reference [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to attach  an event handler function
then use `mouseenter` - use when mouse enter the object
`mouseeleave` - use when mouse leave the object
`click`- use when click on the object

```js
$('.icon-change').on('mouseenter',function(){
 $('.icon-change').css("background-color","red");
});
$('.icon-change').on('mouseleave',function(){
 $('.icon-change').css("background-color","blue");
})
$('.icon-change').on('click',function(){
 $('.icon-change').css("background-color","pink");
});
```

```css
.nav > li > a:hover,
.nav > li > a:focus,
.navbar-header > a:hover,
.navbar-header > a:focus {
  background-color: #7F613F;
}

.icon-color {
  color: #282828;
}
.nav {
  display: flex;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .nav > li {
    float: left;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" style="background-color: #b39369; max-height: 50px;">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <div class="navbar-header">

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-top: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 15px;">
                            <li><a class="icon-change" href="#" style="padding: 15px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment icon-color"></i></a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can handle mouse effect via jquery.

```
$(selector).on('mouseover mouseleave', function(e){
  console.log(e.type)
})
```

check the console.

Answer (score 1):

keep using css, just add a class like 'selected' with `background-color: pink` and toggle it on click

```
$('.icon-change').click((e) => { e.target.toggleClass('selected'); }
```

Answer (score 1):

you use this methods to achieve

```
$(".icon-change").mouseover(function(){
$(this).css("background-color","red")
});
```

similarly you can use other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
var flag = true;
  $(".icon-change").mouseover(function(){
    if(flag) {
      $(".icon-color").css("color", "blue");
    }
  });
  $(".icon-change").mouseleave(function(){
    if(flag) {
      $(".icon-color").css("color", "#282828");
    }
  });
  
  $(".icon-change").click(function(){
    if(flag) {
      $(".icon-color").css("color", "pink");
      flag = false;
    } else {
      $(".icon-color").css("color", "#282828");
      flag = true;
    }
    
  });
```